# 'Danach wir könnten in einem Restaurant essen' is it correct to use the Dativ in this sentence?

Tags: translation

I'm questioning myself whether it should be in ein Restaurant.. but I think as I am using 'essen' I should use the dative and say 'in einem Restaurant' ?

Thank you in advance, I find this forum really helpful

Comment: While Dativ is correct, your sentence structure is incorrect. Danach wir könnten should be Danach könnten wir

Comment: Because the verb comes in second place in German main clauses. Another possibility would be "Wir könnten danach ...".

Comment: @infinitezero thank you :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The German "in" with accusative basically means the English "into", while the German "in" with dative means the English "in".

You can go into a restaurant: "in ein Restaurant gehen".

You can run into a restaurant: "in ein Restaurant rennen".

However, you don't eat **into** a restaurant, you eat **in** a restaurant, so in German,  the dative case is correct: "in einem Restaurant essen".

To put it in a more abstract form: "in" + accusative denotes *direction*, "in" + dative denotes *place*.

If you begin the sentence with "danach", your verb and subject swap places:

> Danach könnten wir in einem Restaurant essen.

Answer (score 3):

Both sentences are correct. They just have slightly different meanings.

> Wir gehen in einem Restaurant essen

answers the question: "Where will you eat?" - "We will eat in a restaurant".

> Wir gehen in ein Restaurant essen

answers the question: "Where will you go to eat?" - "We will go to a restaurant"

Comment: But the question does not say _in ein Restaurant essen gehen_, but _in ein Restaurant essen_ - and this would be wrong, while _Wir gehen in einem Restaurant essen_ does not sound like proper German, since it would mean something like: _Inside a restaurant, we are going for diner_.

Comment: you are right... I somehow assumed the "gehen" to be there...

Comment: @jonathan.scholbach Why is it not proper German? Wir gehen essen. Wir gehen Pizza essen. Wir gehen Pizza in einem Restaurant essen. Wir gehen in einem Restaurant essen.

Comment: You make the same mistake as I did: There is no "gehen" in the question.... I just assumed it was there... "Wir essen in **einem** Restaurant" is correct, whereas "Wir essen in **ein** Restaurant" is not. With "gehen" both expressions are right of course...

Comment: Ich schreibe mal auf Deutsch, da kann ich das besser erklären: In meinen Ohren heißt dieser Satz, dass man _innerhalb eines Restaurants_ (= _in einem Restaurant_) essen geht. Ausgedrückt werden soll aber, dass man _in ein Restaurant geht_ (um zu essen), oder dass man _in einem Restaurant isst_. _in einem Restaurant essen gehen_ drückt das aber nicht aus, sondern sagt aus, dass es gerade das Essen gehen ist, was man im Restaurant macht. Vielleicht macht folgendes kontrastierendes Beispiel das klar: _Wir gehen in einem Restaurant essen, ihr geht in einem Resturant auf Toilette_

Answer (score 2):

As the other answers have pointed out, your use of the Dativ is correct and mandatory in this sentence.

However there is another possibility, with a little change:

> Danach könnten wir in ein Restaurant, essen.

This basically translates to "Afterwards we could go into a restaurant, to eat."

But in this case specifying what you want to do in a restaurant other than eating isn't really necessary. A more reasonable use-case would be "Danach könnten wir in den Park, picknicken." because otherwise it was not inherently clear what you want to do in the park.

Answer (score 0):

In German, common positional prepositions "in"/"auf"/"an" are two-way prepositions. This means they lead accusitive when indicating direction, but dative when indicating location.

The last sentence requires clarification: a two-way preposition leads accusitive, when the subject ("wir" in your example) and the object ("restaurant") changed their relative positions, from non-contact to contact (or contact to non-contact) from a bird's eye view.

Whereas a two-way preposition leads dative, when the subject ("wir" in your example) and the object ("restaurant") do not change their relative positions. They either stay non-contact, or stay in physical contact, from a bird's eye view.

Note that you can eating and running everywhere *within* the restaurant, and it's still dative.